# Android get data from LayoutInflater EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my Activity, dynamically insert a layout that contains an EditText. The layout can have between one and N EditText. How can I get the text of all EditText ?

```
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
final View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflate_ta, null);
           item.addView(child);

MaterialEditText ed = (MaterialEditText) child.findViewById(R.id.ed12);
                 ed.setFloatingLabelText(edNomeCampo.getText().toString());
```

Comment: With a `loop`...save on one variable how many `Edittext` you put  dynamically and make a `loop` to getText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to go through each view within whatever parent view you're dynamically adding to.

so...

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/wrapper"..>
<EditText ... />
<EditText... />
...
...
<!--Nth EditText-->
<EditText... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then once you want to get the values in each dynamically added `EditText` you would iterate through all views within that wrapping `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout yourLinearLayoutView = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
for(int i=0; i<yourLinearLayoutView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View editText= yourLinearLayoutView.getChildAt(i);
    if(editText instanceof EditText){
        String str = ((EditText)editText).getText();
        //from here you can store str in whatever structure you wish (AWrrayList, etc.)
    }
}
```